# How to convert HDF file to GeoTIFF in batch using HEG tool

Tags: geotiff-tiff, hdf

I have 116 MODIS image in HDF format, I want to convert it to GeoTIFF format using HEG tool. How do I convert this multiple files at once?

Comment: Wouldn't it be enough to write a two-line script?

Comment: Thanks, will try it!